# How do I play a sound and pan it in OS X using Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, core-audio

I'm writing a 2D game and I'm looking to play a sound in a lightweight manner while being able to pan it left and right as needed. NSSound is fine for everything, including volume adjustments, but it can't pan.

One other wrinkle: I'm using MonoMac, and AVFoundation is not available. So AVAudioPlayer is a no-go.

From looking at the available APIs the only answer I've found seems to be "use OpenAL", but I'm interested to see if there's any other alternatives. It's a fairly simple 2D game, and I'd rather avoid mucking with positional audio if I can avoid it. (Even panning is sort of optional, it's just a nice-to-have that I'd like to work in if it's not going to ruin my day.)

Answer (score -1):

This late in the (OpenGL) game I'd be using it even for a 2D (sprite) based game; Gamers expect things like parallax, shadowing, textures, etc. so why re-invent the wheel? That said if you understand OpenGL then OpenAL is actually simpler. You can probably get everything you need in less than a half-dozen API's.

If you choose to ignore the above advice… there's always [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html)

Comment: I've used this  (http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/) lib for iOS and it is pretty easy to set up and work with. Core Audio is great but the learning curve is a bit steep.

Comment: I was using OpenGL, actually. OpenGL is not OpenAL, however; it's notably less infuriating. I ended up tubing the project and going with MonoGame, which handles the grunt work.